# Hide Apps from Default Launcher

Tags: java, android, hide, launcher, android-package-managers

How is this possible? I've looked at

```
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName
```

But It seems that isn't the solution. I want to essentially let the user checkbox which apps to hide from their default launcher. There has to be a way without creating my own custom launcher.

Any help would be great all. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But It seems that isn't the solution

It will work for your own app, at best. Some home screen implementations do not detect this change right away, requiring a reboot of the device.

> There as to be a way without creating my own custom launcher.

No, sorry.

Comment: Where's the supporting evidence? ;)

Comment: @r3mus: You cannot prove a negative. With respect to this particular issue, if this *were* possible, I would be contacting the Android Security team regarding a flaw in Android and working to help get it fixed.

Comment: Aye, fair enough! (Not an Android developer myself, just thought the answer seemed a little speculative).

Comment: @CommonsWare There must be a way. There are apps out there that will hide apps from your app drawer.

Comment: @f00d4tehg0dz: Name any.