# how to hide apps from other user in android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-launcher

i am trying to make launcher in android.i want admin to hide few apps from user.
   i have done for admin-user log in. now i want admin to select some apps which should not be seen by user.
   so that,when user log in he/she should see only those apps which are allowed by admin.

```
 List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo ri:availableActivities){
        AppDetail app = new AppDetail();
        app.label = ri.loadLabel(manager);
        app.name = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
        apps.add(app);
    }
```

i have got the list of apps..

kindly help.

Comment: Check these links..it may help you
                    
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549013/hide-apps-from-default-launcher

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117668/android-hiding-disabling-apps-from-menu-without-root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **PackageManager** to get all the installed apps and then write the following code:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, package_name);  //package_name is the name of the application's package you want to hide
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain application information i.e name,package name and icon in SQLite databse.

On the basis of selection , you can show applications to user.